# Swashbuckle - add DisplayName to model properties

Tags: swagger, customization, swashbuckle

I am using Swagger/Swashbuckle in a .NET Core app.
How can I add the display name of my model attributes in swagger.json output file?

Here my model:

```
 public class Role
    {
        [DisplayName("Role Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
    }
```

Here the current output

```
"Role": {
   "properties": {
      "Name": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "Level": {
         "format": "int32",
         "type": "integer"
      }
   }
}
```

Here the desired output:

```
"Role": {
   "properties": {
      "Name": {
         "displayName": "Role Name",
         "type": "string"
      },
      "Level": {
         "displayName": "Level",
         "format": "int32",
         "type": "integer"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not see `"displayName"` anywhere in the swagger spec: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md

Comment: I double checked on the old version (v2.0)  and no displayName there either: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comments the "displayName" is not in the specifications

- Latest:
  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md
- Older version:
  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

I just added that to one of my files to see what will happen during validation:
https://validator.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/56287697_swagger_aws.json

We can see the validator does not like that, we get an error:

```json
{
  "schemaValidationMessages": [ {
    "level": "error",
    "domain": "validation",
    "keyword": "additionalProperties",
    "message": "object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"displayName\"]",
    "schema": {
      "loadingURI": "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#", "pointer": "/definitions/schema"
    }
    ,
    "instance": {
      "pointer": "/definitions/MyData/properties/name"
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

You could propose that change to the specification but don't expect it to get added any time soon:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

---

The only quick option or workaround I see, will be using extensions:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#specification-extensions
You can inject those using an IDocumentFilter:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=IDocumentFilter

Look like the IDocumentFilter has some breaking changes on the latest version:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/2b171c0fc6efe40f3a29a45c48d6b01221a0c214/README.md#document-filters
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/2b171c0fc6efe40f3a29a45c48d6b01221a0c214/README-v5.md#document-filters

Your desired output will change a bit:

```json
"Role": {
   "properties": {
      "Name": {
         "x-displayName": "Role Name",
         "type": "string"
      },
      "Level": {
         "x-displayName": "Level",
         "format": "int32",
         "type": "integer"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you mind adding a code snippet? I will accept the answer

Comment: A code snippet for what? the link for IDocumentFilter has plenty of examples

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `DisplayName() attribute`, you can use `JsonPropertyName() attribute` which is out of the box.

```
public class Role
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Role Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
    }
```